# Drools in stream mode not working in Karaf

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I am new to Drools, investigating to use Drools Fusion CEP for our product. I am  executing Drools (in stream mode) fusion 6.0.2.Final in karaf 2.4.3.

My kmodule.xml

```
<kbase name="sampleKBase" packages="com.sample.heartbeat" eventProcessingMode="stream" default="true">  
    <ksession name="sampleKSession" type="stateful" default="true" clockType="realtime">
    </ksession>
</kbase>
```

And my Rule:

```
package com.sample.heartbeat

import com.sample.droolsfusion.HeartBeat; 

declare HeartBeat  
     @role(event)  
     deviceId : int  
     currentCheckIntime : long  
end  

rule "Sound the alarm"  
when   
   $h: HeartBeat($deviceId : deviceId, $currentCheckIntime: currentCheckIntime) from entry-point "MonitoringStream"  
  not( HeartBeat( deviceId == $deviceId, currentCheckIntime > $currentCheckIntime , this after[0s,10s] $h ) from entry-point "MonitoringStream")  
then   
            // Sound the alarm
    System.out.println("Sound" + $h);  
end
```

When i send events from `BundleActivator`, events are not fired after 10 seconds on missing heartbeat events

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: For reproducing the problem, the Java code that starts the KieSession and inserts the HeartBeat events is required. Please edit your question.

Comment: Hi @laune, i did mistake in my import statement .drl file once i corrected it it is working fine in karaf now. Thanks for helping out.